# Getting information about src block in ```org-src-mode```

Tags: org-mode

I need to configure the behavior of `elpy` when editing a python src block in `org-src-mode`. Usually such configuration code should be added to `org-src-mode-hook`. In my code I need to check some header args and act appropriately: I need to make sure that the code is `python` (not, say `ipython`) and whether the `:session` parameter is set.

The only way I found to do this is to access a "private" and undocumented variable `org-src--babel-info`. Is this the suggested way? Should this be documented in `org-mode`?

In particular my default `elpy` iterpreter is `jupyter` but I need to set it to `python` when editing src code blocks and I need `elpy` to use the running session when pressing `C-c C-c` instead of opening a new one.

Comment: Thanks for asking such an interesting question. Have you looked at `org-element-map` and `org-element-property` functions to extract the header info? I suspect these functions would work but I’m still trying understand how to pass the header data back to hook.

Answer (score 1):

The file `ob-core.el` has a [section `Public API`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org-src.el#L728-L737)  that contains the macro `org-src-do-at-code-block`. You can use that macro to analyze the source code block associated with the source edit buffer.

The following example shows how it can be done. It returns the header arguments as an association list with the header argument names as keys and the values as strings.

```el
(defun org+-edit-src-header-args ()
  "Get header args of the source block currently edited."
  (let* ((el (org-src-do-at-code-block (org-element-context)))
     (parameters-string (org-element-property :parameters el))
     (parameters-list (org-babel-parse-header-arguments parameters-string)))
    parameters-list))
```